# Como Puedo Resolver Este Problema al hacer git push?

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitignore

Estoy haciendo git push para hacer cambios en el repositorio de github con este comando en la consola `git push -fu origin TomasMain` y recibo este error

```
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl/next-swc.linux-x64-musl.node is 100.89 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu/next-swc.linux-x64-gnu.node is 100.98 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:fjmn2001/medine-erp.git
 ! [remote rejected]   TomasMain -> TomasMain (pre-receive hook declined)
error: falló el empuje de algunas referencias a 'github.com:fjmn2001/medine-erp.git'
```

Ya instale git-lfs y me sigue dando el mismo error, aunque no me interesa enviar esos archivos al repositorio, quiero que se ignoren. As que toda la carpeta node_modules la tengo en el .gitignore y sigue dandome el mismo error.

Comment: Ahora están ignorados, pero ¿los incluiste en algún *commit*? Agrega a tu pregunta el `git status` actual.

Comment: no lo creo, es un proyecto grande en el que han trabajado muchas personas, pero en mi local nunca los he incluido

Comment: parece que estas tratando de hacer push de un commit que incluye un archivo de mas de 100mb